# Cancel process of delete a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, delete-row

I need help to cancel a process of deleting a row in mysql using PHP!
The thing is that I want to delete inactive accounts if they have not been active before 24 hours!

How I delete now:

```
DELETE FROM members WHERE passkey_valid <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel"?  You either issue the `DELETE` to the database or you don't.  It's an atomic step, there's nothing to cancel.

Comment: Okay! But the thing is that I want is: if you activate your account, the account will not be deleted.

Comment: Create a column called "validated" with "YES" as a value and upon deletion of others later on, just use `WHERE .... validated !='YES'`

Comment: Okay! I think that will work! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column called "validated" with "YES" as a value and upon deletion of others later on, use `WHERE .... validated !='YES'` as an example.

```
DELETE FROM members WHERE validated !='YES' 
AND passkey_valid <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Your INSERT could resemble something like this:

```
$validated = "YES";

$query = "INSERT INTO members (validated,date) 
    VALUES ('$validated', NOW() )";
```